# Is it possible to use would be + verb + ing

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs, conditionals

If I had gone white-water rafting with my friends, I _____ down the Colorado river right now.

> **A**. Would be floating.
>
> **B**. Would have floated.
>
> **C**. Would float.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the adverbial "right now", you are talking about something that you are doing right now, so you should use a continuous tense. For example, if somebody called you at an inconvenient time, you would say

> I can't talk right now, I am **preparing** for the meeting.

Because it is a hypothetical conditional, you replace **am** with **would be**. Your sentence should therefore be

> If I had gone white-water rafting with my friends, I **would be floating** down the Colorado river right now.